# How to create mirrored transformation of CALayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How to create same effect as making image with such orientation do?

```
[UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:1 orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
```

I am going to use layer transformation, but if you show view transformation, I will probably figure out how to change it to layer one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this will help.

```
CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, -1.0);

image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, -1.0);  // For Top to bottom

image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0); // For left to right
```

Comment: `CATransform3DScale(transform, -1, 1, 1);` works for me, but I have rotated view.